# Start a new session from within tmux with ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh

I have enabled tmux plugin in oh-my-zsh with `ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true` and now every time I open terminal I am attached to a session. That part is really nice.

The problem is – now I can't start a new session and get access to shell.

Is there a way to start a new session without disabling tmux plugi?

```
$ tmux new-session -s new
sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force
```

I have openend a ticket on github: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmuxinator` solved it:

```
tmuxinator start [project]
```

And it breaks through the current `tmux` session straight into the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Without `-d`, `new-session` will automatically attach to the new session (you probably do not want nested sessions<sup>*</sup>, thus the warning). What you probably want to do is create a new “detached” session and then switch the current client to that new session. I do not think `new-session` has an option to handle this use case, but it is fairly easy to do with a bit of shell scripting:

```
tmux-new() {
  if [[ -n $TMUX ]]; then
    tmux switch-client -t "$(TMUX= tmux -S "${TMUX%,*,*}" new-session -dP "$@")"
  else
    tmux new-session "$@"
  fi
}

# example usage:
tmux-new -s new
```

If there is no TMUX, then just run `tmux new …`. Otherwise,

- unset TMUX to avoid the error<sup>†</sup> while using `-S` to point to the current server,
- add `-d` to create a detached session, and
- add `-P` to print out the name of the new session (this requires *tmux* 1.8 or later).

The output (the new session’s name) is then given to `switch-client`.

If you do not have *tmux* 1.8 you might have to rework it a bit (e.g. make the function take a mandatory argument that names the new session so that you can pass it to both `new-session` and `switch-client`).

<sup>* You would have two status bars; it is complicated to type *tmux* commands to the inner session; and it may do odd things if you switch the inner client to view the outer session (think: hall of mirrors).</sup>
<sup>† Maybe the warning should be suppressed when using `-d`…</sup>

Comment: Hmm, something doesn't work here. https://gist.github.com/firedev/204119182d482848bb71

Comment: @Nick: Er, only the first of those gisted commands uses uses the function. It probably needs a `-s` in there (i.e. `tmux-new -s test`), otherwise you are just starting (and switching to) a session with a window that runs the command `test` (which probably just immediately exits with a non-zero result).

Comment: I just tried to run commands in the terminal. `tmux-new -s test` doesn't do anything either.